# Unable to get the attached files from http request in mule 3.4

Tags: http, mule, multipartform-data, mule-studio

Inside a mule flow, I am trying to read the files which i am sending as a part of HTTP Post request. SOAP UI is used for sending the request. In SOAP UI, the method is set as POST and the address is 'http://localhost:10035/mytest/1.0/doctest'

attachments looks like the image given below.

[image]

I am working on MuleStudio with Mule 3.4 server. My in-bound endpoint looks like the one given below.
[image]

I am not able to get the attachments at any point in the flow.

i.e. message.getInboundAttachmentNames() is giving me an empty set inside transformer and #[message.inboundAttachments.size()] is giving me a value of 0.

what could be the reason?

Comment: So your mel expression works but not in the transformer code ? If yes you should pase the full transformer code to get help, otherwise will be hard.

Comment: @MauroRocco Not actually... #[message.inboundAttachments.size()] would give me a value of '0'. Transformer class is not that complex. it just has System.out.println(message.getInboundAttachmentNames()). I am not able to catch the attachments at any point in the flow :(

Comment: Why you don't run it in debug mode and check all http headers in your debug and their contents ? This should help

Comment: @MauroRocco For some reason, My mule studio doesn't support debugging the flow. But i could debug java class, which may not be helpful. Does Mule 3.4 support Http request with attachments as input?